# How to create 2 depends Comparators in java?

Tags: java, sorting, interface, comparator

Lets say I have a `Product` class in Java and 2 `Comparator`s:

1. 1st is price `Comparator` for asc order.
2. 2nd is price `Comparator` for desc order.

It can be that if I changed the 1st to be product name `Comparator`, so, the 2nd will change automatic to name `Comparator`  as well?

Thanks alot!

Exmaple:

```
class ProductComparatorByPriceDesc implements Comparator<Customer> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Product o1, Product o2) {
             return o1.getPrice() - o2.getPrice();
        }
    }

Class ProductComparatorByPriceAsc implements Comparator<Customer> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {
        return o2.getPrice() - o1.getPrice();
    }
}
```

So if i changed the 1st comparator to sort by name, not price, the 2nd will changed as well, but not the opposite!

Comment: I don't understand...

Comment: I don't understand your question, I'm afraid. It would help if you could post a [mcve].

Comment: Added example, is it OK? @Jon Skeet

Comment: Well it's not clear how you'd expect code changes in one comparator to be changed in another - but then you don't need two comparators anyway. Will add an answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet , i know, but that what we asked for and im clueless!

Comment: @ShayZambrovski: It sounds like you should ask for clarification from whoever set you the exercise. I've answered it as best I can in terms of what I would do, but it's still not clear whether the "change" you're talking about is in terms of code or state of an existing object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be:

```
import java.util.*;

class SomeClass {
  public int price;
  public String name;
  public SomeClass(String name, int price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
  }
}

class PriceOrNameComparator implements Comparator<SomeClass> {

  boolean compareByPrice;

  public PriceOrNameComparator byPrice() {
    this.compareByPrice = true;
    return this;
  }

  public PriceOrNameComparator byName() {
    this.compareByPrice = false;
    return this;
  }

  public int compare(SomeClass a, SomeClass b) {
    if (compareByPrice) {
      return a.price - b.price;
    } else {
      return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
    }
  }

  public Comparator<SomeClass> reverseComparator() {
    return new Comparator<SomeClass>() {
      public int compare(SomeClass a, SomeClass b) {
        int res = PriceOrNameComparator.this.compare(a, b);
        if (res == 0) {
          return 0;
        } else {
          return (res > 0) ? -1 : 1;
        }
      }
    };
  }
}

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SomeClass s1 = new SomeClass("a", 5);
    SomeClass s2 = new SomeClass("b", 4);
    PriceOrNameComparator c = new PriceOrNameComparator().byPrice();
    Comparator<SomeClass> r = c.reverseComparator();
    System.out.println(c.compare(s1, s2)); // 1
    System.out.println(r.compare(s1, s2)); // -1
    c.byName();
    System.out.println(c.compare(s1, s2)); // -1
    System.out.println(r.compare(s1, s2)); // 1
  }
}
```

Basically, the outer comparator is configurable, and the inner, reverse order, comparator, being an anonymous inner class, has an implicit reference to the outer comparator and can observe changes in its state.

Comment: Thanks, but i meant that in the code if i change from price to name, so the other comparator will change as well, but it will be only in 1 way. i mean that if the other comparator will change the current field, the 1st comparator will not changed it. @Vlad

Comment: @ShayZambrovski: Are you talking about changing the comparator's *code*, or changing some state within it at execution time?

Comment: Personally, this answer violates the Single Responsibility Principle. I think it's clearer to have small building blocks for comparisons, and then chain them together. Also, your reverse comparator is broken - see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/01/24/spot-the-defect-bad-comparisons-part-two/

Comment: @JonSkeet, no Jon, i'm talking about design time

Comment: @ShayZambrovski: In which case, just have a single class, and then if you change the code for that, it will change everything using that...

Comment: @Vlad Thanks very Much, i still cant vote a + for you, but as soon as i can i'll do so!

Comment: @Vlad, hi vlad gave u fixed the reversed bug?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at @JonSkeet's link to see what he meant. Anyway, I think his answer to your question is more elegant than mine, if it works for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest only having a single comparator class for comparing by price, and a separate comparator class to compare by name (or no classes - see the end of my answer). Each class does one thing, and does it well.

Then you can reverse *any* comparator using the [`Comparator.reversed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--) default method... and likewise you can chain them together using `Comparator.thenComparing`, should you wish to order by name and then price, for example:

```
Comparator<Product> nameThenPrice =
    new NameComparator().thenComparing(new PriceComparator());
```

(If you're not using Java 8, it's easy enough to write a `ReversingComparator` which takes an existing one, and a `CompoundComparator` which takes two existing ones.)

You can also use Java 8's static methods in `Comparator`:

```
Comparator<Product> byName = Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getName());
Comparator<Product> byPrice = Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getPrice());
Comparator<Product> nameThenPrice = byName.thenComparing(byPrice);
```

That way you often don't need to implement `Comparator` at all manually.

Comment: The reversed was just example for another comparator

Comment: @ShayZambrovski: How were we expected to know that from the question? We can only answer the question that's actually asked...

Comment: Thanks very Much, i still cant vote a + for you, but as soon as i can i'll do so!

Comment: @ShayZambrovski You can't upvote, but if this solution solves your problem, you can still accept it.